# Duplicate keystrokes onto remote computer in realtime

Tags: xorg, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share keyboard over network as separate device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46363/share-keyboard-over-network-as-separate-device)

Sort of like a poor man's keyboard sharing. I've tried using Synergy and x2x but couldn't get them to work, so I decided to simplify things and use xdotool to generate the events.

Is there any way to get the keysyms (such as Control_L, F4, Shift_R) of keystrokes so they can be passed on to xdotool?

I've looked at xev but it generates so much information and I have no idea how to extract the info I need (which key was pressed, whether it is being held down, etc.) more or less in real time.

Comment: What do you want to do? ssh to two computers, type once and get the result on both computers?

Comment: More like controlling one computer with the other's keyboard. I tried Synergy, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but

```
xinput test <id>
```

Prints the events generated by input device <id> (see `xinput list` to figure out ids)

```
xev | sed -n '/^KeyPress/{n;n;s/.*, \(.*\)).*/\1/p;}'
```

will return the keysym pressed in the xev window.

```
xmodmap -pk
```

will print mappings between keycodes and keysyms.